# content not showing when clicking nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why my jquery isn't working correctly. I click on my navbar link and the content space shows for .0923202 of a second and goes back to be hidden. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".content").hide();

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".content").show();

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHgpg/

Answer (score 2):

While anchor tags are meant to send users to another page, you're using it to show new content on the page.  You will want to return false to override the default behavior of the anchor tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide();

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".content").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You're likely right about what the anchor tag is doing and how to fix that. Using `event.preventDefault()` is of course another option. But regarding use of a div or span instead of an anchor I would strongly recommend against it because it makes the page inaccessible from the keyboard and therefore unusable for people who are physically unable to (or simply choose not to) use a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: @nnnnnn, good point.  I amended my answer to remove the reference to spans and divs.

Comment: Thanks you for your solution Robbert, I am going to try it now.  @nnnnnn, what would the best practice be for making this issue accessible to everyone? Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for the updated version. Waymond, anchors are fine to make it accessible, and of course they can be styled to look different from a standard textual hyperlink.